# Pass query parms to a page that has a UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass query params to an angular page that uses UI router. My problems is that when I do pass them they get stuck before the /#/.

```
http://someURL/vgclient/?ticket=abc123#/salesOrganization
```

The page that passes to this page does it in the following manner

```
document.location.href = '/vgclient/?ticket='+res.ticket
```

I could do

```
document.location.href = '/vgclient/#/salesOrganization?ticket='+res.ticket
```

But I would prefer not to include the route since #/salesOrganization is the default URL. Any help would be great!

Comment: Is salesOrganization an abstract state?

Comment: why you don't use `$state.go('stateName',{param:1})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled:true,requireBase:false});
```

See here for detailed info: [angularjs docs for $locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider)

HTH